# NSTableView from Array Controller selection NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSArray filled with instances of NSMutableDictionary. I am able to present the master NSTableView with the contents of the array using an array controller. Now, I want to present a detailed ("pivot") view of the current selection in a separate NSTableView.

It occurred to me to try and bind the detail NSTableView to the selection in the Array Controller. However, the selection is an NSMutableDictionary and I have no control over the order of the keys.

Any suggestions? I don't know if this can be solved with Cocoa Bindings... but what I'd like is if I could pivot the selection in my existing NSTableView into its own NSTableView and pick up the transformers and styling that the columns in the master NSTableView already have implemented.

e.g.
MASTER

```
Name Date  Description Price
---- ----  ----------- -----
ABC  02/12 Widget 2    $1.49 < selection
XYZ  03/17 Widget 1    $1.30
```

DETAIL

```
Name          ABC
Date          02/12
Description   Widget 2
Price         $1.49
```

Comment: I think [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsoutlineview_class/reference/reference.html) would suit this rather than table views.

Comment: I looked into NSOutlineView but that is not how my UI needs to work. Think of the left hand side containing the Master rows and the right hand side containing the detail view. I'm sure I can achieve what I want by implementing datasource directly for the 2nd table and not using cocoa bindings, but I wanted to know if there was a way to "pivot" a tableview, e.g. the column headings run down the left side of the table.

Comment: You *can* populate a second detail table with the selection using bindings.  ie bind the detail table's row content to `selection.keys` and have a custom sortDescriptor that sorts the keys into the order you want.  As for the date&number formatters for the cells: this is part of the View and not the Model.  You could have the detail view ask the master view for the NSTableCellView for the key you're displaying in the detail view... but that is likely more pain than it's worth.  I'd think the pain of having to implement the formatters twice in IB is less than creating an automagical solution.